# Editing assembly on Mac OS X

Tags: assembly, macos, mach-o

I'm currently disassembling a Mach-O executable(the executable runs on Mac OS X, to be specific) in IDA Pro on windows. I have one instruction which I want to change, but it doesn't seem that IDA Pro [allows you to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969901/edit-patch-a-binary-file-in-ida-pro). So, I tried using otool on OS X to dump the assembly(which it does fine). However, after editing the assembly in otool, I tried to reassemble it using `as <file name of modified otool -tV output>`. This greets me with a bunch of errors like `Junk character 43 (+)`. What's the easiest way to change just a single instruction in a Mach-O binary on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used both otool and [otx](http://otx.osxninja.com/) to disassemble various binaries, and I've found the easiest way to edit them is to figure out what the assembly of the new code I want is (using [nasm](http://www.nasm.us/) or similar), then just use a hex editor (I prefer [Hex Fiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/)) on the binary file.

Comment: This seems like a horrible solution(though tolerable for small edits), especially considering that x86 has variable-length instructions. Are there no good tools for disassembling and reassembling files on OS X?

Comment: unfurtunely there are no tools like ollydbg on OS X :(

Answer (score 1):

I use **Synalize It!**.

You can load also a custom grammar (example for png files, showing header, tags, etc...)